# Android built in drawable doesn't scale

Tags: android

I have a problem with a drawable. I working on a layout for a tablet, but the drawable doesn't scale.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

The problem is the delete drawable in the top right. 
I used the built in drawable ic_input_delete.

Here is the xml of the edittext and imagebutton:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/inputLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:background="@android:drawable/edit_text"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/pinDisplay"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.85"
        android:background="@null"
        android:hint="@string/pincode_hint"
        android:padding="3dp"
        android:textSize="24sp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/backspace"
        style="@android:style/Widget.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.15"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_delete" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Did you try setting the 'android:scaleType' attribute?

Comment: To what scaleType should I set it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `android:scaleType` to `FIT_XY` or `CENTER_INSIDE`:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html